# Can't connect to EC2 SQL Server unless I open to all IPs

Tags: sql-server, security, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, firewall

Strange issue. I have SQL Server running on an EC2 box that I can connect to remotely fine if I open up all IPs (0.0.0.0/32) for port 1433. If I just open up for the IP I'm connecting from  then it I get a connection error. I can't even ping the server on port 1433 (using [paping](http://code.google.com/p/paping/)) unless I open up to all IPs.

The IP must be right because I have a rule that opens up just my IP for port 3389 to connect using RDP, and that works fine.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm probably missing something simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my experience connecting to SQL server running on EC2 box from my desktop, I had observed that you need to make 2 entries with same IP and port number detail, one for TCP and other one for UDP protocol. Try if that works for you.